# Can't to input file at aside bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I try to create input file at aside bootstrap, but when i click the button for attach the file, pop-up browse file not working. do you know what the problem?

```
<aside id="sidebar-right" class="sidebar-right">
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">File Upload</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
      <div class="input-append">
        <div class="uneditable-input">
          <i class="fa fa-file fileupload-exists"></i>
          <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
        </div>
        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
          <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
          <span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
          <input type="file" />
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you close aside tag? Close it and try again.

Comment: that just missed when i copy this code from my worksheet

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<aside id="sidebar-right" class="sidebar-right">
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">File Upload</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
      <div class="input-append">
        <div class="uneditable-input">
          <i class="fa fa-file fileupload-exists"></i>
          <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
        </div>
        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
          <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
          <span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
          <input type="file" />
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</aside>

</body>
</html>
```

working fine with same code just added  as said in previous answer. 
https://jsfiddle.net/14Lfb7kh/

Comment: but not working in my aside bootstrap. btw, close aside just missed when i copy this code, not in my code

Comment: does this https://jsfiddle.net/14Lfb7kh/ code working or not on jsfiddle